# Flask app not running after closing putty

Tags: flask, putty

I am trying to make a flask web app.
whenever i close my putty the website stops running and even if I make any change in the code then without running again it does not reflect on the web.

Comment: how are you running your app? give us a clue on what to look. my guess is you `ssh`, do a `flask run` and then log out. right?

Comment: yeah i use putty to connect to server and run app llike python3 index.py but when i close the putty the website does not run.

Answer (score 2):

When you close `putty`, you close the process of running the `application` too.
in order for the app to run, you need to `deploy` it.
i give you an example on how to deploy using `Gunicorn` and you should read doc's for other way's to deploy yourself.

do a `pip install` for Gunicorn:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

and then,

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 index:app
```

the `app` in the above line is the variable name you gave to instantiate flask.

```
app = Flask()
```

so, if you have used something other than `app` you should put that in the `index:app` part. `index` is obviously the filename you have your `app` inside.

you can make a `service` and run `Gunicorn` from a file, so even if your server is restarted, it will run at boot.

Answer (score 2):

When you close putty, you are virtually closing down your app also, If you want to access it even when you close down your putty, you should have "tmux installed on you system":

```
pip install tmux
```

Once installed, create a new tmux session by

```
tmux new -s myname
```

Under this session run any code you want (flask app in your case), close the putty and you should still be able to access your app running. You can attach to your session to stop the app via

```
tmux a -t myname
```

or you can simply kill your tmux session. For more details please check https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you have to run your flask app with gunicorn+nginx refer this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04  but for development purpose refer this link to keep your flask app running even after you close your terminal https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session